# How to set the default resolution of safe mode

Tags: resolution, safe-mode

I can set the resolution I want in Settings > Display.  However, I want to know how you can set the **default** resolution of Safe Mode.

Comment: Just curious, why?  Are you finding yourself spending significant time in Safe Mode?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage, yes I am, Windows will not boot to “Normal” Mode.  I reinstalled Windows, and it works for 1 or 2 boots, then fails again.  No RAM problems or any other symptoms.  I’m considering posting a question about this strange issue.

Comment: :( That is indeed another question and a harder problem.  Given that it works for 1 or 2 boots, it could be a driver issue (either you install them or Windows downloads drivers automatically and attempts to apply them, but it causes problems).  Find the latest drivers for all of the devices (and get some slightly older ones as well in case the latest ones are problematic), gather some data, and make another question if necessary.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage, I suspected driver issues, but I stopped automatic driver updates, and it still kept happening.  Maybe Windows Update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but is appears to be possible. I found this information on this [thread](https://www.tenforums.com/graphic-cards/98319-safe-mode-screen-resolution.html).

If Safe Mode is invoked, a new configuration key appears in:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\

After Safe Mode has been started, another key is created, with the resolution that Safe Mode opens with in subkeys \00 and \00\00.

If the display resolution is changed by right-clicking on the desktop and manually selecting the optimum resolution for the display in safe mode, the values in the \00 and the \00\00 subkeys change to the new applied values.

On restarting and selecting F8 safe mode again, the newly selected resolution for safe mode is persistent.

It is important to point out that incorrectly modifying the registry can result in a non working system. And modifying Safe Mode, which is often used to recover from bad settings, is even more dangerous.